# Pandas groupby and then apply to_dict('records')

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,2], 'b': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], 'd': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

And I want to end with the following dict:

```
{1: [{'b':'a', 'd': 1}, {'b': 'a', 'd': 2}, {'b': 'b', 'd': 3}], 2: [{'b': 'c', 'd': 4}]}
```

Basically, I want to group by `a` and for each data frame I want to apply `to_dict('records')`.

What I tried was the following:

```
# dict ok but not a list 
df.groupby('a').agg(list).to_dict('index')
{1: {'b': ['a', 'a', 'b'], 'd': [1, 2, 3]}, 2: {'b': ['c'], 'd': [4]}}
```

```
# the index disappears
df.groupby('a').agg(list).to_dict('records')
[{'b': ['a', 'a', 'b'], 'd': [1, 2, 3]}, {'b': ['c'], 'd': [4]}]
```

```
df.set_index('a').to_dict('index')
ValueError: DataFrame index must be unique for orient='index'
```

I think I can do it using a for-loop but I'm almost sure there is a pythonic way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way using `groupby()` and `apply()`

```
df.groupby('a').apply(lambda x: x[['b','d']].to_dict('records')).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{1: [{'b': 'a', 'd': 1}, {'b': 'a', 'd': 2}, {'b': 'b', 'd': 3}],
 2: [{'b': 'c', 'd': 4}]}
```

Comment: That looks ideal, I would just change the `x[['b', 'd']]` to `x.drop('a', axis=1)` so you don't need to specify all other columns

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
df.assign(dicts=df.drop(columns="a").to_dict("records")).groupby("a")["dicts"].agg(
    list
).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your logic, I think one way to avoid a *for-loop*, is to use [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) inside a *listcomp* to iterate over both columns in // :

```
out = df.groupby("a").apply(lambda x: [{"b": y, "d": z}
                                       for y, z in zip(x["b"], x["d"])]).to_dict()
```

If you need to zip more than two columns (*dynamically*), use this variant :

```
out = df.groupby("a").apply(lambda x: [dict(zip(x.columns[1:], row))
                                 for row in x[x.columns[1:]].to_numpy()]).to_dict()
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)

#{1: [{'b': 'a', 'd': 1}, {'b': 'a', 'd': 2}, {'b': 'b', 'd': 3}], 2: [{'b': 'c', 'd': 4}]}
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Although I didn't specify it in the question, my table has more columns, so it would be ideal for a code that doesn't explicitly the name of each column.

Comment: Got it, I updated my answer accordingly so you won't need to worry about the columns names/number ;)