# Group by a column and get a list of dict of rows in the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

in a dataframe like this:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     5
1     1     3     6
2     2     4     5
3     2     4     6
```

I want to group by col1 and get a list of dict's from the other two coluns like this:

```
   col1  rows_group  
0     1  [{"col_2": 3, "col_3": 5}, {"col_2": 3, "col_3": 6}]
1     2  [{"col_2": 4, "col_3": 5}, {"col_2": 4, "col_3": 6}]
```

how can i achieve this?

Comment: Do you want a solution that applies for more than these 3 columns?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you ask, but I find the answer. Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75324905/pandas-groupby-and-then-apply-to-dictrecords/75325135#75325135

Comment: @rhug123 almost, in this answer the final output it's a list of dicts, what i need its a dataframe with grouped columns in a list of dicts format.  I'm already got it, the answer is in bellow. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found how to achieve this with [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) and [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df.groupby('col1').apply(
    lambda x: x[['col2', 'col3']].to_dict('records')
).reset_index(name='rows_group')
```

Alternatively:

```
(df.set_index('col1').groupby(level=0)
   .apply(lambda g: g.to_dict('records'))
   .reset_index(name='rows_group')
)
```

Output:

```
   col1                                        rows_group
0     1  [{'col2': 3, 'col3': 5}, {'col2': 3, 'col3': 6}]
1     2  [{'col2': 4, 'col3': 5}, {'col2': 4, 'col3': 6}]
```